# wa.me link for WhatsApp Business?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp, whatsapi

I am creating an android app with which you can send message to unsaved contacts in WhatsApp, WhatsApp Business and Telegram. This I do with the [wa.me](https://wa.me) link and the [t.me](https://t.me). link.

I have got the solution for WhatsApp and Telegram but the problem is that I don't know how to get the [wa.me](https://wa.me) link for WhatsApp Business. This link works on both WhatsApp and The WhatsApp Business app. Whenever I click on this link, it redirects me to WhatsApp but not the Business app.

I tried several different types of links. Two of them were:

- https://wa.me/business/$PHONE_NUMBER$
- https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=$PHONE_NUMBER$&source=com.whatsapp.w4b

Here $PHONE_NUMBER$ is the valid WhatsApp phone number of the person whom we want to contact.

Another approach I can think of is that I used the same [wa.me](https://wa.me) link for both Business and Normal but I will disguise one of the link by a URL Shortener. Then I will set it as the ***Open By Default*** link in one of the apps. But I don't know how can I do this through my app. It would great if you help me in this or suggest any other solution.

Thank You!